# Can Python subprocess lose track of what is in my PATH after I import pygmsh module?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Lately I have wanted to use `pygmsh` to help with resampling 3d geometry. Ideally I would like to understand what I'm doing by routinely drawing the output of `pygmsh` calls using `itikz`. However something in `pygmsh` seams to be altering the operating system PATH after I call code of the form:

```py
import pygmsh
with pygmsh.geo.Geometry() as geom:
    geom.add_circle([0.0, 0.0], 1.0, mesh_size=0.2)
    mesh = geom.generate_mesh()
```

If I run the following code before the `pygmsh` cell above I get typical pdflatex output, and a pdf:

```py
from subprocess import check_output

subprocess.check_output(['pdflatex', 'src.tex'])
```

If I run that same cell after the `pygmsh` cell, I get a `FileNotFoundError`.

After playing around with this last night I made the following observations:
The PATH returned by the ipython shell command `!PATH` is being shortened. I have my full path available before calling the `pygmsh` cell, but after it has been substantially reduced.

However the output of `os.environ['PATH']` seams not to change.

I am trying to use `itikz` to draw a diagram of a 3d mesh, generated by `pygmsh` in a jupyter-lab notebook. Ordinarily I can use `itikz` in my notebooks with out issues.

Under the hood the `itikz` cell magic simply saves the contents of a cell to a `.tex` file (ie `'src'tex'`), then calls `pdflatex` on the file using `subprocess.check_output(['pdflatex', 'src.tex'])`. After this it converts the resulting `src.pdf` to an `.svg` image and renders that as the cells output. It seams that the important point though is that `itikz` calls an external program found on the operating system PATH.

This generally works well enough, on it's own.

So I guess I have two questions.

1. What is the best way to find the offending code in the `pygmsh` repository to stamp this bug?
2. Why am I getting different results from the ipython shell command and from `os.environ['PATH']`?

I'm running python version 3.8.6 64bit, on windows 64bit 10.

---

**Additionally**
Scanning the repository for `pygmsh` hasn't yielded any footholds yet.
https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh/search?q=path
If they modify the path maybe they do it by accident. Or they just don't use convenient names.

I have narrowed down the culprit to the `with` statement. Removing that idiom doesn't seam to mess with my path. Not a fix, seams I need to `__enter__()` the `geom` object and `__exit__()` for it to function, and somewhere between these two calls is my culprit!

found it... it's a known issue with `gmsh` [https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues/1142]

Comment: Please don't put a history of breadcrumbs at the *top* of your question. It makes an already hard to follow question require several attempts to parse.

Comment: I did my best to distil the question to the essential parts. My apologies, last night I was agitated. I just wanted to get the work I had intended to do done.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what environment it runs in. That is, the OS, the Python version, is it OS provided, or custom install?

Comment: This is a custom install, yeah. I think the version of python is 3.8.6, (that is the output of `python -V` , though I seam to have a few older python versions hanging out on my system, so I'm not sure which one jupyter is using.

Comment: Yeah, that could be part of the problem. Windows does weird stuff with PATH sometimes, and could have per-process PATH changes in the config. I also found that pygmsh depends on another package, gmsh. That packages uses ctypes to load a DLL. So, who knows? I can't reproduce this on my Linux machine.

Comment: The first few paragraphs are unnecessary, can you move them below the *"However something in pygmsh seems to be altering the OS path..."*"

Comment: Your last line *"found it.."*: please post that as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

The environment of you current process can be modified by a statement in the imported module causing executable resolution relying on search `PATH` to fail, e.g.:

```
subprocess.run("ls")
os.environ["PATH"] = "bogus"
subprocess.run("ls")
```

This will run the first `ls` and fail on the second one.

Manipulating environment of running process is a problematic action and can lead to confusion. But you could also in this case isolate yourself form it by using absolute paths.

But to your edit, to find the offending location, be on a lookout for `os.environ` or `os.putenv`.

Comment: This is helpful, but in this case I don't want to rewrite `itikz` to use absolute paths under the hood, and  `os.environ['PATH']` in `pygmsh` seams to not be used in `pygmsh`, see link above in 3rd edit.

Comment: Since this is not a relative path (so change of cwd is not of relevance, but can be just as surprising when done), it really should be the environment (nested import?). There is one more scenario where you get `ENOENT` (when the executable itself is found, but its interpreter is not (but that is unlikely in this context).

Comment: Perhaps a silly question: Without `shell=True` the `str` value of args should be the executable otherwise a list of argument for `execve`, executable and parameters: `["pdflatex", "this.tex"]`. But I presume that is the code shortening, because that behavior would not change with `import`.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was encountering a [known issue in `gmsh`](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues/1142) which is what is doing the grunt work under the hood of `pygmsh`.

Unfortunatly there isn't really a work around because the fix for this involves passing arguments to a function that `pygmsh` does not fully expose.

In the short term I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh/pull/435) to that repo trying to expose the fix.